# Aggregating raster data at coarser resolution

Tags: r, aggregation, raster, r-sp

I have a dataset that is 0.25 * 0.25 degree grid resolution

```
lon <- c(-53.615449969, -53.365449969, -53.115449969, -53.365449969, 
     -53.115449969, -52.865449969, -53.365449969, -53.115449969, -52.865449969, 
     -52.615449969, -53.365449969, -53.115449969, -52.865449969, -52.615449969, 
     -52.365449969, -53.365449969, -53.115449969, -52.865449969, -52.615449969, 
     -52.365449969, -53.615449969, -53.365449969, -53.115449969, -52.865449969, 
     -52.615449969, -52.365449969, -52.115449969, -53.865449969, -53.615449969, 
     -53.365449969, -53.115449969, -52.865449969, -52.615449969, -52.365449969, 
     -52.115449969, -51.865449969, -54.365449969, -54.115449969, -53.865449969, 
     -53.615449969, -53.365449969, -53.115449969, -52.865449969, -52.615449969, 
     -52.365449969, -52.115449969, -51.865449969, -51.615449969, -54.615449969, 
     -54.365449969, -54.115449969, -53.865449969, -53.615449969, -53.365449969, 
     -53.115449969, -52.865449969, -52.615449969, -52.365449969, -52.115449969, 
     -51.615449969)


lat <- c(-33.627081271, -33.627081271, -33.627081271, -33.377081271, 
     -33.377081271, -33.377081271, -33.127081271, -33.127081271, -33.127081271, 
     -33.127081271, -32.877081271, -32.877081271, -32.877081271, -32.877081271, 
     -32.877081271, -32.627081271, -32.627081271, -32.627081271, -32.627081271, 
     -32.627081271, -32.377081271, -32.377081271, -32.377081271, -32.377081271, 
     -32.377081271, -32.377081271, -32.377081271, -32.127081271, -32.127081271, 
     -32.127081271, -32.127081271, -32.127081271, -32.127081271, -32.127081271, 
     -32.127081271, -32.127081271, -31.877081271, -31.877081271, -31.877081271, 
     -31.877081271, -31.877081271, -31.877081271, -31.877081271, -31.877081271, 
     -31.877081271, -31.877081271, -31.877081271, -31.877081271, -31.627081271, 
     -31.627081271, -31.627081271, -31.627081271, -31.627081271, -31.627081271, 
     -31.627081271, -31.627081271, -31.627081271, -31.627081271, -31.627081271, 
    -31.627081271)

 df <- as.data.frame(cbind(lon, lat))
 df$ID <- 1:nrow(df)
 coordinates(df) <- c(1,2)

 library(raster)
 elev <- getData('alt', country='BRA')

 plot(elev)
 plot(df, add = T)
```

[image]

For each of my 0.25 * 0.25 degree grid square, I want to calculate the mean elevation. How can I do it in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `res(elev)` is `0.008333333` (that is, `1/120`), you want to aggregate with a factor `.25 * 120 = 30`. The simplest approach would be

```
a <- aggregate(elev, 30, fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Now the resolution is as desired, but not the alignment with the raster you specified. Illustrated:

```
r <- rasterFromXYZ(df)
s <- as(r, 'SpatialPolygons')
z <- crop(a, r, snap='out')
plot(z)
plot(s, add=TRUE)
```

Instead you can do:

```
x <- resample(elev, r)
```

or (more precise, but slower)

```
e <- extract(elev, s, fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
s$elev <- e
```

To compare the values

```
z <- rasterize(r, s)
plot(z, e)
```

Comment: A late question but could you explain what is `120` in `1/120` in your first line

Comment: The resolution of the original raster is `0.008333333`, which is `1/120`